# Querying and updating in mongodb using morphia datastore

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia

I have classes as follows:

```
@Entity("Collection_IAGlobals")
public class MoDBIAGlobals {
    @Id
    @Indexed
    String id;

    @Embedded
    Map<EnumChannelType, MoDBChannel> data = new HashMap<EnumChannelType, MoDBChannel>();
}
```

where, MoDBChannel class is:

```
@Entity("Collection_IAGlobals")
@Embedded
public class MoDBChannel extends MoDBTopic {
    @Indexed
    private String channelId;

    @Embedded
    private Map<String, MoDBTopic> data = new HashMap<String, MoDBTopic>();
}
```

and MoDBTopic class is:

```
@Entity("Collection_IAGlobals")
@Embedded
public class MoDBTopic {
    private String topic;
    private Double score1 = 0.0;
    private Double score2 = 0.0;
}
```

and MoDBIA_DAO class:

```
public class MoDBIA_DAO extends BasicDAO<MoDBIAGlobals, String> {
    public MoDBIA_DAO(Mongo mongo, Morphia morphia, String dbName) {
        super(mongo, morphia, dbName);
    }
}
```

I have an object of MoDBIAGlobals class saved as:

```
dataStore.save(globals)
```

where JSON of globals is as follows:

```
{"id":"usr1234",
"data":{"FACEBOOK":{"channelId":"FB1234",
                    "data":{"NO_TOPIC":{"topic":"NO_TOPIC",
                                        "score1":1.0,
                                        "score2":0.0}},
                    "score1":0.0,
                    "score2":0.0}}}
```

[image: JSON of object <code>globals</code>]

Now I want to query so as to get objects of class `MoDBIAGlobals` where `"id"=="usr1234"` and `"channelId"=="FB1234"`. How can I create this query??

I tried like follows but I could not get any result:

```
MoDBIA_DAO dao = new MoDBIA_DAO(mongo, morphia, DB_Name);
Datastore dataStore = morphia.createDatastore(mongo, DB_Name);
Query<MoDBIAGlobals> query = dataStore.createQuery(MoDBIAGlobals.class).disableValidation();

query.field("data.channelId").equal("FB1234");
query.field("data.data.topic").equal("NO_TOPIC");
QueryResults<MoDBIAGlobals> results = dao.find(query);
System.out.println("results: " + results);
System.out.println("results.count: " + results.countAll());
```

it's printing result as:

```
results: { "data.channelId" : "FB1234" , "data.data.topic" : "NO_TOPIC"}
results.count: 0
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this query on mongo shell? What about the following query, it works? `{ "data.channelId" : "FB1234" , "data.data.topic.NO_TOPIC" : "NO_TOPIC"}`

Comment: I'm completely new to mongodb, and working directly through java. Don't have any experience with mongo shell..

Comment: I just checked and it's not giving any result in shell too.. So I guess some mistake in query parameters.. But what is the mistake??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't understand why you're querying for `data.channelId` and `data.data.topic` if you want to find `MoDBIAGlobals` by `id` and `channelId`. And your data modeling it's a quite confusing too. Anyway, seems that your query does not match your document structure. The fields `data.data.topic` and `data.channelId` does not exists. Try to fix replacing with code bellow:

```
MoDBIA_DAO dao = new MoDBIA_DAO(mongo, morphia, DB_Name);
Datastore dataStore = morphia.createDatastore(mongo, DB_Name);
Query<MoDBIAGlobals> query = dataStore.createQuery(MoDBIAGlobals.class).disableValidation();

query.field("data.FACEBOOK.channelId").equal("FB1234");
query.field("data.FACEBOOK.data.topic.NO_TOPIC").equal("NO_TOPIC");
QueryResults<MoDBIAGlobals> results = dao.find(query);
System.out.println("results: " + results);
System.out.println("results.count: " + results.countAll());
```

Now, if you want to query by `id` and `channelId`, try this:

```
MoDBIA_DAO dao = new MoDBIA_DAO(mongo, morphia, DB_Name);
Datastore dataStore = morphia.createDatastore(mongo, DB_Name);
Query<MoDBIAGlobals> query = dataStore.createQuery(MoDBIAGlobals.class).disableValidation();

query.field("data.FACEBOOK.channelId").equal("FB1234");
query.field("id").equal("user1234");

QueryResults<MoDBIAGlobals> results = dao.find(query);
System.out.println("results: " + results);
System.out.println("results.count: " + results.countAll());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Actually I was trying like `"data.channelId"` / `"data(FACEBOOK).channelId"` / `FACEBOOK.channelId` .. etc. Now I got that `map-key` need to be used and that too with `dot` instead of `parenthesis`.. Thanks.

Comment: also let me know how can I query on map, e.g. I want to check if `data` contain a key `FACEBOOK`, something like `query.field("data").containKey(EnumChannelType.FACEBOOK.name());` or `query.field("data").containKey(EnumChannelType.FACEBOOK);`??

Comment: I figured it out.. it can be done by.. `query.field("data."+EnumChannelType.FACEBOOK.name()).exists();`